# Any way to check if an Activity in android is registered in manifest file?

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

Is there any way to check if an Activity in android is registered in manifest file before starting it?

say eg:

```
 String test = "com.Hy5.activity.Navigate";  
             Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(this.context,
                 test);                  intent.putExtra("params", params);  


            try {  
                ((Activity) context).startActivity(intent);  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                            //e.printStackTrace();
        } // This Activity will implement
```

Here I want to check if Test activity has been registered in manifest or not.

Or is there any way I can read/parse this manifest.xml in application package just like i do for say: getResources().getString(R.string.Sprint1)??

Comment: What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: no issue.. I have a requirement. where in I get activity name as a JSON object and I have to start that activity by calling Intent.  So if it is not registered in manifest, i should not do this startActivity(intent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PackageManager.getActivityInfo()
It will throw PackageManager.NameNotFoundException if it's not there

Not sure you will gain anything by doing this though.

Answer (score 1):

If you get ActivityNotFound Exception, that usually means it is not registered in manifest. You could do something with that.