# Reading android manifest file

Tags: android, file, manifest

Is there any way we can read/parse android manifest file as we do it for files in raw folder as mentioned here:

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/writeSD.html

getResources.ReadManifest..something like this??

thanks
Sneha

Comment: What are u trying to access from the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit after OP's comment] : You can use Android's PackageManaer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html 
to get information about the contents of the manifest file that Android understands.

Comment: i want to check the <activity> tag and see if an Activity is registered in the manifest or not.

Comment: What is a "registered" activity ? You want to know if an activity will respond to an Intent ?

Comment: yes.. I want to know if an activity has been declared in manifset or not before starting it using intent as told here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186272/any-way-to-check-if-an-activity-in-android-is-registered-in-manifest-file

Comment: I answered above, use getActivityInfo()

Answer (score 7):

As already suggested, you can use the `PackageManager` for this purpose. There are several methods that are able to return one or more `PackageInfo` objects, which on their turn contain a public field [`ActivityInfo[] activities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#activities), provided you instruct it too... read below.

The documentation mentions the following:

> Array of all  tags included under , or null if
>   there were none. This is only filled in if the flag GET_ACTIVITIES was
>   set.

So make sure that you provide that particular flag when requesting the info; e.g. when using [`getPackageInfo(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), do:

```
getPackageInfo("your.package.name", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
```

If you need to retrieve more details, you can 'or' multiple flags together:

```
getPackageInfo("your.package.name", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES | PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS)
```

**Edit:**

Alternatively you could also use the [`getActivityInfo(android.content.ComponentName, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getActivityInfo%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29) and catch the `NameNotFoundException` that will be thrown if the requested `Activity` cannot be found, but generally this is considered 'abusing' exceptions.

Anyways, up to you.